# Highchart not printing json when I add extra line to redirect

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

I would like some help if possible. I am using highcharts to produce a chart. I have a data.php file that produces my array.

The array is created by a dynamic query from a form and using json_encode. After the array is printed : print $array_final1;
I want to redirect to the page I have my chart: demo.php by using header('location: demo.php'); on the next line.

If I add the redirect line it takes me to the page but no data is imported into the graph.

data.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$con = mysql_connect("","","");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$start = $_SESSION['start'];
$end = $_SESSION['end'];
$agent = $_SESSION['Agent'];

mysql_select_db("db", $con);

$query = mysql_query("QUERY";

$category = array();
$category['name'] = 'Col';

$series1 = array();
$series1['name'] = 'Total';



while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $category['data'][] = $r['Col'];
    $series1['data'][] = $r['Total'];  
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$category);
array_push($result,$series1);


$array_final = json_encode($result);
$array_final1 = preg_replace('/"(-?\d+\.?\d*)"/', '$1', json_encode($result));

print $array_final1;

header('location: demo.php');

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I recommend you should research exactly what happens on a redirect and how they work.

Comment: "the server returns a Location header as part of the return to the browser which tells the browser not to load this page and go to this location instead." Ok got your point. Can I redirect to a page after loading the page?

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want to do?  You want to load the page and then redirect the browser to a new page immediately?  What is the point of loading the page if you are just going to redirect?

Comment: I have a form (form.php) that actions data.php which builds the query and prints my array. Then I have another page (graph.php) that I have my highchart which I only know how to use with: $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) to graph my array. My goal is, as soon as the user presses submit form, the array to be created in data.php and the user to by directed to graph.php.

Answer (score 0):

Of course no data is imported, you aren't sending anything.

Since you are already using a session, why don't you put the data you want to use in the other page into `$_SESSION` ?

```
$_SESSION['array_final'] = $array_final1;

// the redirect
```

-- in demo.php --

just use

```
$_SESSION['array_final']
```

Comment: I only know how to read the chart's data from another file:  $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
    options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
          options.series[0] = json[1];
          chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as you, but I found a way around it.

If I understand your question correctly, you have a data.php page which grabs data from MySQL and generates an array list for the Highcharts javascript to read. And in the demo.php page, you have the Highcharts javascript which calls data.php to get the information.

There is no need to do redirect with the header('location...'). In demo.php page, you should generate a session to store the value and in data.php check if the session has a value, else do something or nothing.

Below is my example,

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['sort'])){
        $from=$_POST['SDate'];
        $to=$_POST['EDate'];
        $sTime=$_POST['STime'];
        $eTime=$_POST['ETime'];
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['start']=$from." ".$sTime;
        $_SESSION['end']=$to." ".$eTime;
        }
        ?>
```

I have a button name/id='sort', which onclick will run the above code. It will grab the selected values of 4 drop down lists and append them together to form a start date/time and end date/time, which is then stored into 2 session objects for use.

Now in data.php I have,

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['start'])){
$starter = $_SESSION['start'];
$ender = $_SESSION['end'];

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE roomID='501' AND (dateTime BETWEEN '$starter' AND '$ender') ORDER BY recordID");
$rows = array();
$rows['name'] = 'DateTime';
while($rr = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
$rows['data'][] = $rr['dateTime'];
}

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE roomID='501' AND (dateTime BETWEEN '$starter' AND '$ender') ORDER BY recordID");
$rows1 = array();
$rows1['name'] = 'RoomTemperature';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) {
$rows1['data'][] = $r['roomTemp'];
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows);
array_push($result,$rows1);

$help = print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($con);

}  
else{ 
//do something or nothing
}
```

Hence each time I click the button 'sort', whatever is selected in the drop down lists are stored in session which data.php will be able to grab. You can destroy the session objects if you wish after the Highcharts javascript portion in demo.php if I am not wrong.

Hope this helps.